# Como posso colocar um efeito semelhante ao box-shadow do CSS em um layout no Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Ex.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
    android:........ ?

>
</LinearLayout>
```

Como o do aplicativo da OLX:

[image: Foto do APP da Olx]

Comment: Nas versões menores que 5.0 não existe a noção de sombra, e é um pouco complicado simular isso... Minha sugestão seria criar um `FrameLayout` englobando o `LinearLayout` e colocar uma `<View>` com background escuro e alpha simulando uma sombra ou usar um `9patch` como fundo (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android)... Na versão 5.0 existe a propriedade `elevation`, que da essa sensação de sombra (https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).

Comment: Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, mas não deu certo...<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white"

Comment: Esta rodando em um dispositivo/Emulador com Android 5+? Eu recomendaria usar um elevation de 6dp ou mais para ter uma boa percepção.

Comment: @Wakim Funciounou no 5.0 sim, mt obrigado pela ajuda.. Mas esseda OLX aparece no meu celular, sendo que o meu Android é 4.4...

Comment: Qual tipo de sombra você diz? Do Card ou do ActionBar?

Comment: Use o [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) que consegue fazer isso :)

Comment: Nossa @JorgeB. migrar pro `PhoneGap` só pra aplicar sombras é tenso hehe. Mas Igor, o OLX deve estar usando um `CardView` (AppCompat), não sabia que era esse tipo de sombra que queria, esse efeito é bem simples de se conseguir. Se puder use o `CardView` da support library. Se não puder use este `Drawable` (https://gist.github.com/wakim/c68fcd7d13f98cc1e61b) como background.

Comment: @Wakim não é o caso de migrar. Mas devia ponderar o phonegap :)

Comment: Desculpe pela demora... @Wakim não conhecia o CardView, vou usá-lo no meu projeto. Obrigado !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este tipo de efeito é bem utilizado no **Material Design**. Ele é baseado no `CardView` e/ou `RecyclerView`.

Abaixo mostrarei como é fácil fazer este tipo de efeito.

> drawable/layout_shadow_white.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

   <item
       android:left="0dp"
       android:right="0dp"
       android:top="0dp"
       android:bottom="2dp">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
           <corners android:radius="5dp" />
       </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

> layout/my_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow_white"
    android:id="@+id/rel_anything"></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow_white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_newgame"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/rel_anything2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow_white"
    android:id="@+id/rel_editor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_culpado"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

Uso: `android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow_white"`

> Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]